# I never seem to have a farm animal stuck in love mode

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

To give some background, I used to know if I had an uneven number of farm animals because one of them would still emit heart particles after feeding all of them. Now, I never seem to have a lone cow stuck in love mode, which is odd to me because that should happen every other time.

So my question is, is this just chance (maybe I missed an animal), or is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of 3 possible explanations:

- You actually have an even number of cows. Or you missed a few and only fed an even number of them.
- You have the particles effect disabled in your settings.
- You have a gazillion of cows, and don't have enough time to find the one with the heart particles. "Love mode" only lasts for 30 seconds.

My bet would be on the first option. It's not true that every other time you should have an odd number of cows. For example:

1. You feed 8 cows and get 4 baby cows.
2. Now you have 12, and make 6 more.
3. You have 18, so 9 more babies.
4. Finally you have an odd number of cows, in your 4th time breeding them.

Have you checked how much wheat you spend in a whole feeding round? That would definitely tell you how many you fed. (Unless you go nuts, like I do, spam feeding them... then you may actually feed some of the babies too)

Comment: Yeah I see the faulty math there now,  I'm honestly not sure which one is the case but now it won't drive me crazy at least